Question clarifying Serre functors
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr A}\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$Let $\A$ be a $k$-linear category over some field $k$. Then a Serre functor $S$ is an equivalence of categories $S:\A\rightarrow \A$ such that for all objects $A,B$ of $\A$ there exists an isomorphism:
$$\eta_{A,B}:\Hom(A,B)\longrightarrow \Hom(B,S(A))^*$$
which is functorial in $A$ and $B$.
I am trying to make sure I am understanding this functorial property correctly, so let $\phi:A\rightarrow A'$ be a morphism. Then we have an induced morphism $\phi^*
:\Hom(A',B)\rightarrow \Hom(A,B)$, by $f\longmapsto f\circ \phi$. We also have an induced map $S(\phi)_*:\Hom(B,S(A))\rightarrow \Hom(B,S(A'))$ by $g\mapsto S(\phi)\circ g$. This gives a dual map $(S(\phi)_*)^d$ in the opposite direction by applying the dual functor. Is the functorial in $A$ property then that for any morphism $\phi:A\rightarrow A'$ we have the following equality:
$$\eta_{A,B}\circ\phi^*=(S(\phi)_*)^d\circ \eta_{A',B}$$
I have something similar for functorial in $B$ but I won't bore you with details.
I think this is right because it seems to be the only thing I can do, but I am worried it is wrong because the second map feels so contrived.

Yes that is right. But you should say that it is natural in $A$ and $B$. (I have seen some texts to write "functorial" when they actually mean "natural", but I think that this is a clash of terminologies that should be avoided.)
To say in which way it is natural, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. We just use general facts to construct two functors. Then we require an isomorphism between these two functors (that is, a natural isomorphism).
First, the hom-functor is a functor $\mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Vect}$. This is the functor on the left side.
Let's define the second functor. First, we swap the variables. This is an isomorphism of categories
$\mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}^{op}.$
Then, we apply the functor $S \times \mathrm{id}$, which goes from $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}^{op}$ to itself.
The hom-functor for $\mathcal{A}$ may be dualized to a functor
$\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}^{op} \to \mathbf{Vect}^{op}.$
And finally, we have the dual vector space as a functor $\mathbf{Vect}^{op} \to \mathbf{Vect}$.
Composing all these functors gives another functor $\mathcal{A}^{op} \times \mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Vect}$.
And these two functors are required to be isomorphic. To be precise, the isomorphism belongs to the data of a "Serre category" (unfortunately that term is already taken). We do not just assert the existence of some isomorphism, that is almost always a bad decision.
